# ngRoute keeps falling back to .otherwise route after using back button

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have 2 pages: `/teams` and team edit page `/teamedit/:1`, here's the routes:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    var viewBase = '/views/';

    $routeProvider
        .when('/teams', {
            controller: 'teamsController',
            templateUrl: viewBase + 'teams/teams.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/teamedit/:id', {
            controller: 'teamEditController',
            templateUrl: viewBase + 'teams/teamEdit.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/agents' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Here's the steps what cause me problem:

1. On `/teams` page click button what opens `/teamedit/1` page. For that im using `$location.path(url + team);` in the controller.
2. `/teamedit/1` is loaded and i click browser back button

Now back on `/teams` page i click the button again what should take me to the `/teamedit/1` page but all it does is loads that bage for a second (controller code and everything is executed) but then redirects back to the page whats set in `.otherwise`.

There is no reason why it should fall back to the `otherwise`, how can i fix this?

EDIT: Adding code. 
Button what opens /teamedit page:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.edit('/teamedit/', team.teamId)"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</button>
```

teamsController:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('actionSyncAdminApp')
        .controller('teamsController', teamsController);

    teamsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'teamsService', 'broadcaster', 'ngProgressFactory'];

    function teamsController($scope, $location, teamsService, broadcaster, ngProgressFactory) {
        $scope.title = 'teamsController';

        var vm = this;

        vm.progressbar = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();
        vm.progressbar.setParent(document.getElementById('sub-page'));

        vm.teams = [];

        vm.new = function (url) {
            $location.path(url);
        };
        vm.edit = function (url, team) {
            console.log(url + team);
            $location.path(url + team);
        };

        activate();

        function activate() {
            vm.progressbar.start();
            teamsService.getTeams().then(function (teams) {
                vm.progressbar.complete();
                vm.teams = teams;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: this could be caused by something in your controller. Please show us that code

Comment: `$location.path(url + team)` Please make sure `url` variable must have `/` at the end of the string otherwise your URL will become `/teamedit1` which can redirect to `otherwise`

Comment: @AJFunk, i added extra code to original post.
@MaheshSinghChouhan, yes i have the `/` in the end of url. Check code from original post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was just a silly mistake on my part. I had the `button` inside a `<a href ></a>` like this:

```
<a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
    <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.edit('/teamedit/', team.teamId)"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</button>
    </span>
</a>
```

Strange thou this only broke the button after i had used back button and not the first time after page load. Anyway all good now :)